# Including war dependencies with "mvn jetty:run"

Tags: java, maven

I've a war project that includes other war dependencies as "overlays". I can run the project using "mvn jetty:run-exploded".

However, if i try with "mvn jetty:run", it will not work (stuff expected from dependent war is not found). It does not take the war dependencies (specified in pom.xml) into consideration.

My understanding is that "mvn jetty:run" uses src directory as web resources.

Q: Any way to make "mvn jetty:run" take war dependencies into considerations automatically?

I am trying to find the fastest way to develop with maven jetty plugin, jetty:run-exploded can be a bit slow even with -DskipTests.